# Can you remove and add instructions in a disassembler (e.g dbg)?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Recently I decided to learn a new skill - Reading disassembled code.

I want to know if it's possible to remove and add instructions within disassemblers like dbg? I struggle to find that information anywhere on the internet.

I know I can edit instruction lines. I know I can set the instruction lines to 'NOP' which basically makes those lines do nothing, but the memory is still being called during this process.

Can I truly 'delete' that line, and what's more add a new line with a new instructions? If I understand correctly that might require memory editing but how would I go about that?

Comment: If you were to add or remove code, that would require you to adjust every single reference to any code that comes after it.

Comment: @SolomonUcko so what you are saying is that is it not worth it? Deleting code is fine I guess as you can insert 'NOP'. But, then is there any better way of inserting any functionality into a compiled assembly?

Comment: A pure disassembler is a tool like `objdump -d` or `ndisasm`.  It's not a hex editor or debugger, and won't modify the binary file or the in-memory process image respectively.  Some hex / machine-code editors have disassemblers built-in to help if you want to modify instructions in-place in an executable; is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, so I am using a disassembler called DBG. It has hex editor, debugger and basically probably everything I will ever need. It's a complicated software and while I was able to find tutorials on how to do simple stuff, I struggle to really find any more in-depth tutorials about it or any other 'all-round' disassembler. Even basic tutorials there are not a lot of them. 

So like I said, I can modify the lines of code, so if there is 'je xxx' I can modify that line to any instruction I want, but I can't really add a new line of instruction or delete it entirely.

Comment: @DawidWawrzynczyk: Learning how asm works in general (e.g. by following tutorials and reading compiler output) and then understanding some about machine code will make it a lot more obvious what's possible and what isn't.  E.g. the fact that many instructions will include relative or absolute addresses, and there can be jump tables with absolute addresses as data make it impossible in general to safely insert code and move all later bytes later.

Comment: Also, stop calling DBG just "a disassembler"; that's one of its features but what you're asking about is its binary/hex editor.  You're unlikely to find a tutorial on everything it's possible to do with it, because there are so many different possible use-cases for modifying a binary. I'd expect most people to approach the different things you can do with it separately.  And there are other tools like https://github.com/WerWolv/ImHex that are also hex editors with disassembler / assembler built-in.

Comment: Anyway, yes, you're correct, there's no sane way to just delete a `je xxx` instruction, only replace it with a NOP.

Comment: @PeterCordes okay, thank you for those pointers I understand that more now. I have a long experience in high level programming but not so much in low level assembly, and especially not in reverse engineering, there is a lot to learn for me, but it seems hard.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an instruction, you would need to identify the location of the instruction in the binary code, and then overwrite that section of the binary code with a NOP instruction or a sequence of NOP instructions. This effectively removes the original instruction from the program.

To add a new instruction, you would need to identify a suitable location in the binary code where you can insert the new instruction. You would then need to overwrite the surrounding code to make room for the new instruction and insert the new instruction in the correct format.

It's important to note that modifying the disassembled code or binary code directly can be dangerous and could introduce new bugs or security vulnerabilities. Therefore, it is recommended to avoid this unless you are experienced with assembly language and low-level programming.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can learn about all this?

Any pointers, any sources?

Comment: @DawidWawrzynczyk: Some keywords to google: "code cave", and the concept of "hooking" functions.  If you don't have room (e.g. between functions) for new machine-code you want to add, you might add a new section to an executable and replace the first 5 bytes of some functions with a `jmp` into your new section (e.g. on x86.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you. See, without those keywords I would really struggle to find anything useful, thank you!